# Angular js Cancel button functionality issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to implement 'Cancel' button functionality. After clicking 'Apply' button, if I make any changes to modesList after clicking 'Cancel'  button these changes have to be reverted back. For example, initially I have Air and InterModal checked,  after clicking 'Apply', I have selected 'LTL' also. Now I have Air, InterModal and LTL checked. When I click 'Cancel' I expect LTL should be uncheked and only Air and InterModal remain checked. But it is not working as expected.  Please see my plunker at  http://plnkr.co/edit/2wte2rgMA4RfQbuxItin?p=preview. I have even used angular copy but still it is not working.

```
    $scope.cancel2 = function(){

        angular.copy($scope.modesList, $scope.cancelModesList);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how your controller code should look like ([**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdPLNRd6jYpYwnqwo33u?p=preview)):

```
$scope.modesList = [
  // list
];

$scope.applyFilter = function() {
  $scope.cancelModesList = angular.copy($scope.modesList);
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
  $scope.modesList = angular.copy($scope.cancelModesList);
};

// apply the original copy
$scope.applyFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is now you are replacing your list by the cancelModeList which is empty. It is normal that you would have nothing displayed anymore. You should simply put in your cancelModeList an initial list used as reference :

```
  $scope.cancelModesList = [
  {
    "name": "Air",
    "checked": true,
    "id": "186",
    "type": "group"
  },
  {
    "name": "FTL",
    "checked": false,
    "id": "11114",
    "type": "group"
  },
  {
    "name": "InterModal",
    "checked": true,
    "id": "188",
    "type": "group"
  },
  {
    "name": "LTL",
    "checked": false,
    "id": "185",
    "type": "group"
  }]
```

an then use the angular copy :

```
$scope.cancel2 = function(){                
    angular.copy($scope.cancelModesList, $scope.modesList);
};
```